# Caching return value of an extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Here is pseudo code of what this would look like if I could modify the class in question

```
public class Foo
{
    private TheDataType _Data;
    public TheDataType GetData()
    {
        if (_Data != null)
            return _Data;

        // fetch/generate data

        return _Data;
    }
}
```

How do I turn this into an extension method? The definition/scope of the `_Data` is what bothers me...

================================================

This is probably the closest to what I want, but feel like an overkill for something so simple

```
public static class FooExtensions
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Foo,TheDataType> DataCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Foo,TheDataType>();
    public static TheDataType GetData(this Foo foo)
    {
        TheDataType data;
        if (DataCache.TryGetValue(foo, out data))
            return data

        // fetch/generate data

        DataCache.Add(foo, data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What class are you trying to extend? This may be a case of "you want to use extension methods because they're cool, but you really don't need one."

Comment: @SpikeX I just want a simple instance-level cache for a method that does something evil and is called quiet often.

Answer (score 3):

You could have your extension method utilize a cache manager class (custom or built into the framework) which kept track of the data based on some unique identifier for the instance:

```
public static DataType GetData( this Foo obj )
{
    DataType retVal;

    // this sample doesn't show any locking, i.e. it is not thread safe

    // if cache manager contains data return from there
    if( CacheManager.HasData( obj.UniqueId ) )
    {
         retVal = CacheManager.GetData( obj.UniqueId );
    }    
    else
    {
         // otherwise invoke a method on obj and add to cache
         retVal = obj.GetData();
         CacheManager.Add( obj.UniqueId, retVal );
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

However, this strikes me as a potential misuse of an extension method, even though it's syntactically clean. It would depend on the context in which it is used and on how obvious the side effects were. For example this would be really hard for another developer to troubleshoot if they didn't know that GetData() was using a cache, the cache expiration wasn't clear, etc.

Comment: I was actually going to use `ConcurrentDictionary` in case the thing I want is impossible, which it sounds like it is. Definitely +1 for effort though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good fit for function caching, described in [this blog post of mine](http://www.executableintent.com/functional-caching/). The idea is to take a function with one argument and turn it into another function which caches the result of the original one:

```
public static Func<TKey, TValue> Cached<TKey, TValue>(this Func<TKey, TValue> valueFunction)
{
    var cache = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    return key =>
    {
        TValue value;

        if(!cache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            value = valueFunction(key);

            cache[key] = value;
        }

        return value;
    };
}
```

The cache dictionary gets embedded inside the returned closure, so it will have the same lifetime of the function we return.

You would use it by replacing the original call to get the data with the new function:

```
public class UsesTheDataType
{
    private readonly Func<Foo, TheDataType> _generateData;

    public UsesTheDataType()
    {
        _generateData = GenerateData;

        _generateData = _generateData.Cached();
    }

    public void UseTheDataType(Foo foo)
    {
        var theDataType = _generateData(foo);

        // theDataType is either a new value or cached value
    }

    private TheDataType GenerateData(Foo foo)
    {
        // Only called the first time for each foo
    }
}
```

The nice part here is that the caching is written once *for all functions*, so you can reuse the same approach no matter what you have to cache. This also avoids possible memory leaks resulting from the use of a static cache.

This can also be done in a thread-safe manner. See the [second post in the series](http://www.executableintent.com/functional-caching-part-2-concurrency/) for a walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if I follow, it would look something like.

```
public static class FlargExtensions
{
    private static Flarg flarg;

    public static Flarg GetData(this Flarg flarg)
    {
        if (FlargExtensions.flarg != null)
            return Class1.flarg;

        FlargExtensions.flarg = new Flarg();
        return FlargExtensions.flarg;
    }
}

public class Flarg
{
}
```

Comment: It is almost certainly the case that the OP wants to cache at an *instance* level, not in a static context.

Comment: It is quite possible. However, the OP is not quite clear on his intent. This is a case where example use cases would be more helpful than class definitions.